# Cannot install windows on a wiped drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, dvd, cd

About a week or two ago I was on my laptop with Windows 7 (That I installed with a cd) When it dropped.

After dropping the Hard drive I could not find anything on the disk or save anything onto the disk, so I ordered a new HDD (Western Digital 500gb) and tried to install Windows onto it.

Both the CD and USB Drive did not work. After trying a few times on each I gave up and installed Ubuntu which is my backup OS. I always keep on a USB (In case when I am working on my computer something goes wrong).  It installs quickly and easily.

I am wishing to get back the simple download and run to install software (also I need my software back only for Windows) so I keep editing the following BIOS options:

- SATA type AHCI or IDE
- FastBoot On or Off
- Safe Boot On or Off

I need some help installing Windows back on my Laptop from Ubuntu.  For some reason it will not let me install Windows through anything like USB with WinUSB or Rufus.

My Laptop is Asus X551ca the version of windows on my USB is Windows 10 Technical Preview, the version of Windows I am using is 7 Home Premium, which have both been on this Laptop/NoteBook before.  I really need help this is a big problem because I use my Laptop everyday.

tl;dr

My computer gets stuck on Starting Windows on W7 HP CD, Please help, Thank You.

Update: No longer trying with USB only going for CD need help! Please!

Comment: It seems that you are able to start the process by booting from a USB (at least to bootstrap the install of Linux). But then you say the USB is not readable during for windows install. Wouldn't this imply that the USB *is* readable, but the content/software on the USB drive is the issue. I'm mentioning this because its difficult to understand your description.

Comment: the file I am using for the USB is now Win7 and it worked on my Desktop

Answer (score 0):

After searching for 6 hours and trying random things I decided to give it another try myself. Fixed it in 4 Minutes..... Found a setting in the BIOS under Launch CSM..... Launch CSM [Enabled], SafeBoot [Disabled], The thing under Launch CSM [Enabled] Worked better than ever. I have found my product key and now currently on Windows 10 Preview Downloading Windows 8.1 which I will activate and have it fixed. Thank You. Hope this helps someone.